# How to get left padding on PAGE not to the previous outputText?

Tags: visualforce, ui

I have two objects

1. Top Object
2. SubObject

Now under SubObject , I have two types of records 1. Parent  2. Child

Parent record can have child parents and it's child .

For example -

----> Parent1

```
               ----> Parent2

                          ----> Child1_of_P2

              ----> Child1_of_P1
              ----> Child2_of_P1
```

and so on now (refer image[image])

---

I am using "**apex:repeat**" to show record of each level . for current scenario 4 lists have been used

(    1. for Parent1

2. for children of Parent1 holding values of ChildX_of_P1
3. Sub Parents of parent1(Parent2 , as in image) and
4. children of Parent2 )

---

Each child record contains different details like duration , resource etc.

Now the challenge is this to give a padding such that duration and other details are ALIGNED at same distance from left side of page .

---

### VF code for the same is as below

---

```
    <!-- Level 2  Starts here -->
    <apex:outputPanel id="Parent2">
        <apex:repeat value="{!p2_list}" var="Parent2">
            <apex:commandLink value="+" action="{!Parent2_func}" reRender="Child2" style="padding-left:30px;" >
                <apex:param value="{!Parent2.id}" name="milestoneChildid1"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
            <span style="font-size:13px;color:blue"><apex:outputText value="{!Parent2.Human_Name_c}"/> </span>
            <span style="padding-left: 650px;font-size:13px;color:purple">  <apex:outputText value="{!Parent2.Duration__c}"/></span >          
            <span style="float:right;font-size:13px;color:Green"> <apex:outputField value="{!Parent2.Resource__c}"/></span ><hr/>    <br/>
            <br/>   


            <apex:outputPanel id="Child2">
                <apex:repeat value="{!c2_list}" var="Child2">

                    <span style="font-size:13px;color:blue"><apex:outputText value="{!Child2.Human_Name_c}"/></span >
                    <span style="padding-left: 350px;font-size:13px;color:purple"> <apex:outputText value="{!Child2.Duration__c}"/></span >     
                    <span style="padding-left: 130px;font-size:13px;color:Green">   <apex:outputField value="{!Child2.Resource__c}"/></span >             
                    <hr/>   <br/>
                    <br/>                    

                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <!-- Level 2  Ends  here -->       

    <apex:outputPanel id="Child1">
        <apex:repeat value="{!c1_list}" var="Child1">

            <span style="font-size:13px;color:blue"><apex:outputText value="{!Child2.Human_Name_c}"/></span >
            <span style="padding-left: 350px;font-size:13px;color:purple"> <apex:outputText value="{!Child2.Duration__c}"/></span >     
            <span style="padding-left: 130px;font-size:13px;color:Green">   <apex:outputField value="{!Child2.Resource__c}"/></span >             
            <hr/>   <br/>
            <br/>                    

        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:outputPanel>


</apex:repeat>
```

Can anybody please help me to get the DURATION And RESOURCE aligned properly ?

Comment: Try to use `<apex:pageblockTable`. You don't have to use your style to move things. If required use wrapper class and build the data model accordingly.

Comment: I am using multiple list to show data . Thus pageblockTable doesn't seems good to use .

Comment: why not use a wrapper class with nested wrapper class to model the tree in the controller and jQuery Tree View to handle the display in a nice way?